# How is 42 the answer to Life, the universe and the everything?

Tags: number-theory

Entering phrase **"the answer to life the universe and everything"** on Google, **42** appears as search result! Is there any mathematical relevance of 42? What makes this number so "answerable" to life, the universe and everything!?

I read wiki links but did not understand anything, neither I found any satisfactory answer on Quora.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This has nothing to do with math and everything to do with the books The Hitchhikers guide to the galaxy written by Douglas Adams

Comment: See here: https://www.quora.com/Why-and-how-is-42-the-answer-to-life-the-universe-and-everything

Comment: It's a joke from [The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy)

Comment: The novel : [The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_(novel)) is amusing : nothing to do with math !

Comment: Why bother the downvotes? OP showed his efforts but failed since Google is also following the joke. Famous though the joke is, I feel it's inappropriate to blame someone just because he doesn't know it before and  considers it a math problem.

Comment: It is featured in the sequence $4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42$ as well.

Comment: What do you get when you multiply six by nine?

Answer (score 6):

This is not mathematics.

It is a reference to *The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy* by Douglas Adams (originally a series of radio plays, later a wildly popular series of books, also adapted as movies), in which it is a plot point that "the answer to the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything" is known to be the number $42$ -- but unfortunately it is unknown *which question* "the ultimate question of life, the universe, and everything" is, so knowing that answer is not very helpful.

In short, it's a joke.

Comment: Besides, it’s [$47$ that rules the universe](http://www.47.net/47society/), as (most) every Pomona College graduate knows! (I was a year behind the author of that piece.)